# Text in aligned-environment

Tags: formatting, align

Is it possible, that the text starts at the second line of the equation?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item First thing:
      $\begin{aligned}[t]
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      d^2&=e^2+f^2
      \end{aligned},$
      where $a,b$ and $c$ are supposed to be real numbers and $d,e$ and $f$ complex numbers, respectively.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: anything is possible but it would look pretty weird, I would put the `where`... under the alignment

Comment: Ok, how would I do that? And anyway, how would I achieve my first idea? Then I can decide what's better :)

Comment: Replace `t` by `b`.

Comment: No, that's not good, then the `First thing` is also moved to the bottom.

Comment: So, by *text* you mean *where...*?

Comment: Yep, indeed .. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do 3 or 4

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First thing:
      $\begin{aligned}[t]
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      d^2&=e^2+f^2
      \end{aligned},$
      where $a,b$ and $c$ are supposed to be real numbers and $d,e$ and $f$ complex numbers, respectively.
\item First thing:
      \begin{align*}
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      d^2&=e^2+f^2
      \end{align*}
      where $a,b$ and $c$ are supposed to be real numbers and $d,e$ and $f$ complex numbers, respectively.
\item First thing:\vspace{-5pt}
      \begin{align*}
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      d^2&=e^2+f^2
      \end{align*}
      where $a,b$ and $c$ are supposed to be real numbers and $d,e$ and $f$ complex numbers, respectively.
\item First thing:
      $\begin{aligned}[t]
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      d^2&=e^2+f^2
      \end{aligned},$

      where $a,b$ and $c$ are supposed to be real numbers and $d,e$ and $f$ complex numbers, respectively.

\item \mbox{}\\[-10pt]\raisebox{17pt}{First thing:}
      $\begin{aligned}[b]
      c^2&=a^2+b^2\\
      d^2&=e^2+f^2
      \end{aligned},$
      where $a,b$ and $c$ are supposed to be real numbers and $d,e$ and $f$ complex numbers, respectively.
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

Comment: not every document class fails to indent a new paragraph in a list.

Comment: @barbarabeeton true but one thing at a time:-) (might be a rare case that `\\ ` is better than a blank line, I agree.

Comment: no; if you're using `aligned` (which is sensible), `\\ ` doesn't yield the same vertical spacing.  it would be `\noindent`.